# MYSQL filter multiply row by two lists of id

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have results:

```
item_id     subitem_id
----------------------
1           35
1           25
1           8
2           10
2           25
3           60
4           35
4           25
4           44
5           1
5           23
5           15
5           13
5           9
```

and I have two lists of subitem

```
(25,44,1)
(8,9)
```

how do I set the where clause in order to filter the result and return this

```
item_id     subitem_id
----------------------
1           35
1           25   <-- first set
1           8    <-- second set
-----------------
5           1    <-- first set
5           23
5           15
5           13
5           9    <-- second set
```

because this `item_id` contain both `subitem_id` from two lists

```
SELECT 
    `item_id`
FROM table
WHERE `subitem_id` in (25,44,1)
AND `subitem_id` in (8,9)
```

Did not work, because in one time `subitem_id` have one id (not all list)

P.S.
This is a simple example, in reality we have more than 100k records with some join construction

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE subitem_id in (25,44,1) OR subitem_id in (8,9)`?

Comment: Can you explain the logic? why `item_id = 1`  return the same 3 row as original, but `item_id = 5`  return 5 of 6 ?

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza, sorry this is mistacke of copy paste

Comment: @kyeiti im cant us or, because in result would be rows content only one of list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c64f/6/0)

I think you're trying to make sure a item_ID has subcategories in 2 differen sets..

```
Select * from table A
where exists (Select 1 from table B where A.Item_Id = B.Item_ID and subitem_ID in (25,44,1))
  and exists (Select 1 from table C where A.Item_Id = C.Item_ID and subitem_ID in (8,9))
```

Comment: yes. im try check what item id has both subitem form 2 category. but what was faster subquery like @Juan Carlos Oropeza or your variant?

Comment: Too difficult to tell indexes, data size all play a role in performance.  You'd have to test both and find out.  I do know exists can use the index and stop looking once a single occurrence is found.

Comment: Gelid As @Alex said my aproach was wrong (*very wrong*).

Comment: @Gelid can you post speed test result vs my query please?

Comment: @Alex Without index is hard to see which one is faster. But you can compare execution plans. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71c28e5/8  but looks like your `JOIN` generate a bigger table to start with.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  Man... how long has that link for execution results been there on sqlfiddle?  (I learned something new today thanks!)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes and no. explanation is good tool. but xQbert query seems VERY unperformant to me since it generates subquery for every record.

Comment: @xQbert not sure how long, but I have use it a lot :P

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza here is my proof done by OP : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/feaba/2/0 so using `EXPLAIN` is good practice but it does not really  show everything

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71c28e5/3

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.item_id)
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t1 t2
ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
  AND t2.subitem_id in (8,9)
WHERE t1.subitem_id in (25,44,1)
  ) t
LEFT JOIN t1
ON t.item_id = t1.item_id
```

Another approach to avoid big number of executed records for mysql:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71c28e5/10

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
WHERE item_id in (
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.item_id)
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t1 t2
ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
  AND t2.subitem_id in (25,44,1)
WHERE t1.subitem_id in (8,9)
  )
```

Comment: 2nd one is much better performance wise according to but still seems on par with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/feaba/2/0  I added a bunch more data.

Comment: ? according to the fiddle provided both my queries took 2 ms vs 189 ms of not mine one? what do you call better performance?